# How to copy from CSV file to PostgreSQL table with headers (including special characters) in CSV file?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have 500 different CSV files in a folder.

I want to take a CSV file and import to Postgres table.

There are unknown number of columns in csv so I do not want to keep opening CSV file, then create table and then import using `\copy`

I know I can do this:

```
COPY users FROM 'user_data.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER
```

However, the CSV file is something like:

```
user_id,5username,pas$.word
1,test,pass
2,test2,query
```

I have to convert this to postgres, but postgres does not allow column name to start with number or special character like `.` and `$` in the column name.

I want the postgres table to look something like:

```
user_id     ___5username      pas______word
1           test              pass
2           test2             query
```

I want to replace special characters with `___` and if column name starts with number, then prefix with `___`.

Is there a way to do this? I am open to a Python or Postgres solution.

Answer (score 0):

If `pandas` is an option for you, try to:

1. Create data frames from the CSV files using [`.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
2. Save the created data frames into SQL database with [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

You can also see [my tutorial on `pandas` IO API](https://realpython.com/pandas-read-write-files/).